# Delete colon from filenames and links to them in html-file

Tags: command-line

I got a large photo collection as nested directory consisting of jpg files and html files linking to them groupwise.

The filenames of the photos look all like

```
2014-11-22T13:41:33_IXUS95_IMG_0880.jpg
```

and within the html files these names occur eg as

```
<title>Image: 2014-11-22T13:41:33_IXUS95_IMG_0880.jpg (9/796)</title>
```

or

```
<img src="slides/slide_2014-11-22T13:41:33_IXUS95_IMG_0880.jpg" width=933 height=700 border=1>
```

The directory layout looks something like

```
2014/ - 2014.01/ - 100.html
                   101.html
                   slides/slide_2014-11-22T13:41:33_IXUS95_IMG_0880.jpg
                   thumbs/thumb_ 2014-11-22T13:41:33_IXUS95_IMG_0880.jpg
      - 2014.02/
2015/ - 2015.01/
```

....and so on....

How can i get rid of the colons in both, filename of the images and the links to them within the html-files?

Comment: You want to simply replace the colons in all file names of the images and all textual representations of those file names in the html files with e.g. a `-`? Or remove them without replacement?

Comment: Split the problem in half: How can I rename the `.jpg` files to "get rid of the colons", and How can I apply the SAME change as textual alteration to the contents of the `*.html` files.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they are replaced or deleted without any replacement. I want to do this because when I copy this whole directory tree onto a USB drive (with vfat filesystem) the filesystem will allow filenames with the colon in them, but any windows system will not be able to display the image gallery.

Answer (score 1):

This part will rename your files. 
**for file in $(find . -name "*T??:??:??*")

do

     mv -i "${file}" "${file//:/}"

done**
This part will replace filename in your *.html files
**for file in $(find . -type f -name "*.html")
 
do

    sed -i -re 's/([[:digit:]]{2}):/\1/g' $file 

done**